# bootstrap 3 responsive embed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3's responsive embed code but for some reason, I always have a huge gap under the object I am embedding.

This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe>code goes here</iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS is bootstrap's stock:

```
.embed-responsive-16by9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

I can reduce the bottom padding by manipulating the above css but that doesn't seem to be the way this should work.

Do I perhaps have to wrap the embed code in another div?

Comment: Please add an image of what you are seeing and maybe the full code!

Comment: The embed-responsive-16by9 class will give you a 16:9 aspect ratio. I sounds like you want a different aspect ratio? Bootstrap has a few other helper classes for different aspect ratios, but if none of those suit then you should define your own padding-bottom value like you've already done.